# Frame jerking in my game loop

Tags: html, canvas, 2d-games, game-loop

I'm hoping someone will be able to point out what's going wrong with my code as I've been looking at it long enough to go crazy. I'm implementing a side-scrolling auto runner using HTML5 and running into some issues with the frame rate jerking. It works perfectly on my Macbook Air and almost as good on my Nexus 4, but when I deploy to my iPhone 4 I notice some annoying jerking in the frame rate. Keep in mind that I am using CocoonJS so there should be no issue with Canvas performance.

I spent ages investigating possible performance issues but when I took a step back it appeared to something a lot more basic than that. It appeared that the issue may be with my game loop itself. I created a more basic example that reproduces the same issue that I have. It's quick and dirty code so apologies for that but it demonstrates my problem.

I have a game loop implemented by looking at one of the examples here http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/comment-page-2/#comment-3877. I haven't implemented interpolation because I didn't think it was necessary for something this basic. To be closer to a lower end device I've thrown in a for-loop writing to the console (dirty, I know), so with the web debugger open I get 30 UPS and ~60FPS on my Macbook Air.

Occasionally though when the frame rate dips I'll experience this frame jerking where the moving blocks on the screen jump a noticeable amount. It was my understanding that as long as my FPS stays above the UPS then I shouldn't really notice this behaviour. To see what I mean just uncomment the for-loop.

Can someone point out what the issue is here? or if this is even a valid test? Any help much appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>setInterval Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="viewport" height="480" width="640"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  Game.initialize();

  Game.run = (function() {
    var loops = 0, skipTicks = 1000 / Game.ups,
        maxFrameSkip = 20,
        nextGameTick = (new Date).getTime();

    return function() {
      loops = 0;

      while ((new Date).getTime() > nextGameTick && loops < maxFrameSkip) {
        //for(var i = 0; i <= 250; i++) { console.log('test') }
        Game.update(); 
        nextGameTick += skipTicks;
        loops++;
        Game.logUpdate();

      }

      Game.draw();
      Game.drawFrames();
      Game.logFrame();
    };
  })();

  window.setInterval(Game.run, 0);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
////// GAME //////////
var Game = {};
Game.ups = 30;

Game.initialize = function() {
  this.frames = 0;  
  this.updates = 0;
  this.updatesPerSecond=0;

  this.blockA = new Rect(50, 50);
  this.blockB = new Rect(250, 50);
  this.blockC = new Rect(500, 50);

  this.context = document.getElementById("viewport").getContext("2d");
  this.context.font = "bold 18px Arial";

  this.previousUpdateTime = 0;
  this.previousTime = 0;
};

Game.draw = function() {
  this.context.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
  this.blockA.draw(this.context);
  this.blockB.draw(this.context);
  this.blockC.draw(this.context);
};

Game.update = function() {
  this.blockA.update();
  this.blockB.update();
  this.blockC.update();
};

Game.logUpdate = function() {
    this.updates++;                    
    this.currentUpdateTime = new Date().getTime();

    if((this.currentUpdateTime - this.previousUpdateTime) >= 1000) {
        this.updatesPerSecond = this.updates;
        this.previousUpdateTime = this.currentUpdateTime;
        this.currentUpdateTime = 0;
        this.updates = 0;   
    }
};

Game.logFrame = function(){
  this.frames++;                
  this.currentTime = new Date().getTime();

  if((this.currentTime - this.previousTime) >= 1000) {
    this.fps = this.frames;
    this.previousTime = this.currentTime;
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.frames = 0;        
  }
};

Game.drawFrames = function() {
  this.context.fillText("UPS: " + this.ups, 20, 180);
  this.context.fillText("FPS: " + this.fps, 20, 150);
};
//////// RECT ///////////
function Rect(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velocity = -4;
};

Rect.prototype.draw = function(context) {
  context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 30, 30);
};

Rect.prototype.update = function() {
  if (this.x < -30) {
    this.x = 640;
  } 

  this.x += this.velocity;
};
```

Comment: I think the problem might just be that the iPhone 4 is running some kind of expensive internal process which causes your UPS to become greater than than the FPS. It's creating a massive delta. The loop can't to anything about it except try and catch by calling `update` multiple times until the sprite position have caught up, and that causes the jump you see. I don't think that's anything you can control. Your code looks like classic fixed-timestep-variable-rendering, so I think the problem is with the iPhone 4. But I might be wrong, so hopefully someone else out there can comment on this.

Comment: I agree with @d13 that your lag is probably due to device-limitations. Mobile has fewer resources to handle required system activity so FPS will suffer.  It might help to substitute `requestAnimationFrame` for `setInterval`. RAF synchronizes itself with device refresh cycles and may reduce the lags during required system activity. The new versions of RAF are fed a timestamp parameter that you can use to properly position your game elements even if a frame was lost due to system activity.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments. The thing is that I'm displaying the UPS and FPS in my game and the FPS never (even when it's lagging) drops below the UPS. Worst case scenario my UPS is its constant 30 and FPS is 45. Surely if this was the case then I shouldn't see any lag?

Comment: Can anyone else provide some insight. I actually notice this on my macbook air slightly so I know its not hardware specific